# Applications hook

Tags: windows, hook

I would like to make some hook in windows programs. For instance, Vodafone application have some MSN like popup that can't be hiddent. So, in that way, I would like to create my option to hide or not this popups. Can anybody tell me some tutorials (basic first) how to do that?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create system wide windows hook with [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) with first param [WH_CBT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can hook on HCBT_CREATEWND event and return non zero value and window will be destroyed, but first you have to somehow recognize that this is right window, maybe according to window title or something inside that title.

Another thing is that you can't use managed code and C# for system wide hooks, since you have to make unmanaged dll in witch hook will reside. So you have to use C++ or Delphi, and if you are not experienced in win32 programming that would probably be very complicated task.